# Stream live audio device with VLC from the command line

Tags: macos, http, audio, command-line, vlc

I need a way to stream live audio over HTTP with VLC from the command line. I've been able to do this with the GUI, but it's inefficient, and I was hoping I could do the same thing with a shell script. I've looked at VLC's wiki and guides, but there has been nothing about streaming audio live from a device. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: so you're looking for a streaming server ... what would be your audio rendering client ?  an app / some browser client ...

Comment: @ScottStensland My Raspberry Pi is the client and it can play HTTP URLs. The program is called PiFMPlay and is used to stream FM radio from various sources. I'm trying to use VLC on my mac as a streaming server so the Pi can receive microphone and computer audio from a local IP.